React Native drawer navigation giving error as [Reanimated] Failed to create a worklet, Cannot read property 'isConfigured' of undefined
I am learning react navigation and facing issues on drawer navigation.
Below is my code and package details.
dependencies in package.json
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.15",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.26",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.16.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.12.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.10.4",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.31.1"

babel.config.js
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:@react-native/babel-preset'],
  plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
};

code
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import {createDrawerNavigator} from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import Home from './Screens/Home';
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Router = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator>
        <Drawer.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={Home} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
export default Router;

I am getting error as

Error: [Reanimated] Failed to create a worklet. See https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/guides/troubleshooting#failed-to-create-a-worklet for more details., js engine: herme
TypeError: Cannot read property 'isConfigured' of undefined

I have tried deleting node module and reinstall all dependencies, also tried:
npx react-native run-ios -- --reset-cache
Things are working fine when using stack navigator, but not working when using drawer navigator.
Please help me in resolving this issue. I am using M1 chip MacBook and trying to build the app on iOS simulator.

have you tried doing a pod install?

Yes, i did pod install after every dependency removal or addition

You could try pod cache clean && pod install but I read somewhere that creating a new project also fixed this error
